# Find most accurate match in strings

Tags: c#, comparison, compare, match

I'm developing a tool which fixes incorrect filenames by searching the correct names on a YouTube playlist. This tool gets the YouTube playlist videos' titles and stores them in a List:

```
static List<string> tracksList = new List<string>();
```

After storing all correct names in this List, the tool performs a search in a folder, it will only search on files with '.mp3' extension:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\folder");
FileInfo[] files = musicDir.GetFiles("*.mp3", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

After storing all MP3 files in a `FileInfo` array, it loops through all of them. This loop will go file by file and, with the filename of each file, will check which is the most similar value that is in the trackList List. I have already tried with this, but it did return an empty array:

```
var trackMatch = tracksList.Where(track => track.Contains(file.Name.Replace(".mp3", "")))
                           .ToArray();
```

Is there any way I could do that?

Comment: The line of code you used just produces a list, that won't change the file name, what is the specifc problem you are having?

Comment: by "any stored value" if you mean a word in the title, you will have a problem with common words and articles.  Then there would be the issue of titles without meta data (`[FULL HQ + HD]`) but otherwise match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String comparisons can be performed by using Levenshtein's algorithm ([more information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)). The implementations for this algorithm can be found [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#C.23).

The function (that will count how many characters have to be changed to have the other string) is the following (taken from https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#C.23):

```
public static int LevenshteinDistance(string source, string target)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(target)) return 0;
            return target.Length;
    }
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(target)) return source.Length;

    if (source.Length > target.Length)
    {
        var temp = target;
        target = source;
        source = temp;
    }

    var m = target.Length;
    var n = source.Length;
    var distance = new int[2, m + 1];
    // Initialize the distance 'matrix'
    for (var j = 1; j <= m; j++) distance[0, j] = j;

    var currentRow = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        currentRow = i & 1;
        distance[currentRow, 0] = i;
        var previousRow = currentRow ^ 1;
        for (var j = 1; j <= m; j++)
        {
            var cost = (target[j - 1] == source[i - 1] ? 0 : 1);
            distance[currentRow, j] = Math.Min(Math.Min(
                distance[previousRow, j] + 1,
                distance[currentRow, j - 1] + 1),
                distance[previousRow, j - 1] + cost);
        }
    }
    return distance[currentRow, m];
}
```

Therefore, if use the previous function for comparing an input string with every string stored in tracksList, we will get Levenshtein value: the lowest one will mean that it's the most similar:

```
static List<int> matchList = new List<int>();
foreach (string Track in tracksList)
{
    matchList.Add(LevenshteinDistance(Track, "Dailucia   Where My Heart Matches The Beat (Ft Poprebel) [FULL HQ + HD]"));
}
string match = tracksList.ElementAt(matchList.IndexOf(matchList.Min()));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a non-trivial task.

The problem of course is that the errors in the filenames can be **anything**, from spelling errors to left out words to added spaces..

This means that **any** character can be affected in **any** way.

Therefore neither a simplistic `Contains` nor even a smart `RegEx` will work reliably.

I would split the filename into **words** and do a **count** of how many of the word I find in the list titles. The one with the highest count has the best chance to be the right one.

I would also try to go for a semi-automatic program, where I get offered the choices ordered by hit count and then can confirm, correct or pass..